# Android: Add view onclick after the view itself

Tags: android, layout, onclick, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` View with a `OnClick`handler and I want to add a View after the LinearLayout programatically when the OnClick event is fired.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout info = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.infolayer, null);
    // view.addViewAfter(info)
}
```

`info` is the View i want to add. `view` is the View on which the click goes and after which I want to add `info`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

IF u want add a view after the current linear layout then first get the id of the parent layout in which the linear layout is .

for example let u have the the Linear Layout with id  "ll" in relative layout(having id parentlayout) and on a button click u want add the text view under the liner layout

```
public void onClick(View view) {

RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(this);

TextView tv=new TextView(this)
//set param value ur requirement
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.ll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a known amount of linearlayouts could you just place them inside the XML resource and mark them as 'GONE'. When the event occurs make them visible. When they are marked as gone they shouldnt be taking any screen space up.

Comment: Yea, I already thought about this option but I don't want it to be in the XML. It has to be inserted by code.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert through coding and you don't need to inflate. You can create a view of any type calling the constructor and passing the context. A reference to the context can be stored on the view as a field, when the view is being constructed. This way you can always create your view on the fly.

To add the view to the `LinearLayout`, you just need to call `addView`. And afterwards, if you would want to remove it, just call `removeView`.

But the `onClick` event is inside the `LinearLayout` object? This might be a problem because the views inside the the `LinearLayout` might consume the event before it reaches your method. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext/4165892#4165892) to learn about that.

Comment: You didn't get the question right. I dont want to insert a `View` inside a `LinearLayout` but rather insert the view AFTER the LinearLayout.