# EditText, clear focus on touch outside

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

My layout contains `ListView`, `SurfaceView` and `EditText`. When I click on the `EditText`, it receives focus and the on-screen keyboard pops up. When I click somewhere outside of the `EditText`, it still has the focus (it shouldn't).
I guess I could set up `OnTouchListener`'s on the other views in layout and manually clear the `EditText`'s focus. But seems too hackish...

I also have the same situation in the other layout - list view with different types of items, some of which have `EditText`'s inside. They act just like I wrote above.

The task is to make `EditText` lose focus when user touches something outside of it.

I've seen similar questions here, but haven't found any solution...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I tried all these solutions. edc598's was the closest to working, but touch events did not trigger on other `View`s contained in the layout. In case anyone needs this behavior, this is what I ended up doing:

I created an (invisible) `FrameLayout` called *touchInterceptor* as the last `View` in the layout so that it overlays everything (**edit:** you also have to use a `RelativeLayout` as the parent layout and give the *touchInterceptor* `fill_parent` attributes). Then I used it to intercept touches and determine if the touch was on top of the `EditText` or not:

```
FrameLayout touchInterceptor = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.touchInterceptor);
touchInterceptor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (mEditText.isFocused()) {
                Rect outRect = new Rect();
                mEditText.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
                if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                    mEditText.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Return false to let the touch handling fall through.

It's hacky, but it's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: You can do the same thing without adding an additional layout by overriding dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) in your activity.

Comment: thanks for the clearFocus() hint, it also worked for me on SearchView

Comment: I would like to hint to @zMan's answer below. It is based on this, but doesn't need a view http://stackoverflow.com/a/28939113/969016

Comment: Also, if anyone encounters with a situation that keyboard not hiding but focus clearing, first invoke `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` then clear focus

Comment: But it is must to add android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to the top most parent.

Answer (score 301):

Building on Ken's answer, here's the most modular copy-and-paste solution.

No XML needed.

Put it in your Activity and it'll apply to all EditTexts including those within fragments within that activity.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if ( v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                v.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
}
```

Comment: Seems fine. Still I am having one issue, All my edit text are inside a scroll view and the top edit text always have the cursor visible. Even when I click outside, the focus is lost and keyboard is gone, but the cursor is still visible in top edit text.

Comment: Best Solution I came across!! Earlier I was using   
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v.getId()!=search_box.getId()){
            if(search_box.hasFocus()) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search_box.getWindowToken(), 0);
               search_box.clearFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: Great job. Btw. you need to add the code for dialog fragments as well as dialogs have their own root views. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024297/is-there-an-equivalent-for-dispatchtouchevent-from-activity-in-dialog-or-dialo on how to accomplish a dispatchTouchEvent method for DialogFragments.

Comment: Great solution, though in my case, with multiple EditTexts in a list view, a white keyboard-sized rectangle remained on the screen of my Samsung S7 while scrolling. To fix it, I had to add `return true` to the method after hiding the keyboard.

Comment: If the user clicks on another EditText then the keyboard closes and reopens immediately. To solve this I changed `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` on your code. Great answer btw !

Comment: I used this version as well but the comment from @Thanasis1101 did not work for me. I will post my working version code which will keep the keyboard open if the next view is also an edit text

Comment: very neat... yet  having multiple EditText brings flickering keyboard, @Thanasis1101 answer didn't worked for me

Comment: Still works like a charm after all these years.  Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

Just put these properties in the top most parent.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: FYI : Though it works for most of the cases, its not working for layout's some inner elements.

Comment: Without this, the solution provided as best answer not working. I'm using fragments so I need to put `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in FrameLayout. I'm using sdk version 29 with com.google.android.material:material library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this solution will mess up the accessibility of your app. This causes TalkBack to think the top most parent is an interactable element and will read it out to the user as such

Answer (score 36):

For the EditText's parent view, let the following 3 attributes be "**true**":
**clickable**, **focusable**, **focusableInTouchMode**.

If a view want to receive focus, it must satisfy these 3 conditions.

See **android.view** :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ...
    if (((viewFlags & CLICKABLE) == CLICKABLE || 
        (viewFlags & LONG_CLICKABLE) == LONG_CLICKABLE)) {
        ...
        if (isFocusable() && isFocusableInTouchMode()
            && !isFocused()) {
                focusTaken = requestFocus();
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Totally right: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#View.onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Comment: In order to clear focus the other focusable view must be parent of the focused view. It won't work if the view to focus is on another hierarchy.

Comment: Technically, your statement is incorrect. The parent view has to be `(clickable) *OR* (focusable *AND* focusableInTouchMode)` ;)

Answer (score 18):

Ken's answer works, but it is hacky. As pcans alludes to in the answer's comment, the same thing could be done with dispatchTouchEvent. This solution is cleaner as it avoids having to hack the XML with a transparent, dummy FrameLayout. Here is what that looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    EditText mEditText = findViewById(R.id.mEditText);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (mEditText.isFocused()) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            mEditText.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                mEditText.clearFocus();
                //
                // Hide keyboard
                //
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Me Below things Worked -

1.**Adding `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the `parentLayout` of `EditText`i.e `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/employeeID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="Employee ID"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-62dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

2.**Overriding `dispatchTouchEvent` in Activity class and inserting `hideKeyboard()` function**

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View view = getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null && view instanceof EditText) {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                view.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
                int rawX = (int)ev.getRawX();
                int rawY = (int)ev.getRawY();
                if (!r.contains(rawX, rawY)) {
                    view.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

3.**Adding `setOnFocusChangeListener` for EditText**

```
EmployeeId.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    hideKeyboard(v);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

This is my Version based on zMan's code. It will not hide the keyboard if the next view also is an edit text. It will also not hide the keyboard if the user just scrolls the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        downX = (int) event.getRawX();
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            int x = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y = (int) event.getRawY();
            //Was it a scroll - If skip all
            if (Math.abs(downX - x) > 5) {
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            }
            final int reducePx = 25;
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            //Bounding box is to big, reduce it just a little bit
            outRect.inset(reducePx, reducePx);
            if (!outRect.contains(x, y)) {
                v.clearFocus();
                boolean touchTargetIsEditText = false;
                //Check if another editText has been touched
                for (View vi : v.getRootView().getTouchables()) {
                    if (vi instanceof EditText) {
                        Rect clickedViewRect = new Rect();
                        vi.getGlobalVisibleRect(clickedViewRect);
                        //Bounding box is to big, reduce it just a little bit
                        clickedViewRect.inset(reducePx, reducePx);
                        if (clickedViewRect.contains(x, y)) {
                            touchTargetIsEditText = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!touchTargetIsEditText) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: useful, thanks... used a modified version of this to suit my own needs better but thanks for the pointer!

Comment: How is `downX` defined?

Comment: `private int downX;` Nothing more. Simple class member variable

Answer (score 5):

You've probably found the answer to this problem already but I've been looking on how to solve this and still can't really find exactly what I was looking for so I figured I'd post it here.

What I did was the following (this is very generalized, purpose is to give you an idea of how to proceed, copying and pasting all the code will not work O:D ):

First have the EditText and any other views you want in your program wrapped by a single view. In my case I used a LinearLayout to wrap everything.

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText"/>
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code you have to set a Touch Listener to your main LinearLayout.

```
final EditText searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
mainLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(searchEditText.isFocused()){
                if(event.getY() >= 72){
                    //Will only enter this if the EditText already has focus
                    //And if a touch event happens outside of the EditText
                    //Which in my case is at the top of my layout
                    //and 72 pixels long
                    searchEditText.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps some people. Or at least helps them start solving their problem.

Comment: Yes, I've come to similar solution too. Then I ported a subset of android view system to c++ on opengl and built this feature in it)

Comment: This is really a very neat example. I was looking for a code like this but all I could find was complex solutions. I used both the X-Y coordinate to be more precise as I had few multi-line EditText as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have a `ListView` comprised of `EditText` views. The scenario says that after editing text in one or more row(s) we should click on a button called "finish". I used `onFocusChanged` on the `EditText` view inside of `listView` but after clicking on finish the data is not being saved. The problem was solved by adding

```
listView.clearFocus();
```

inside the `onClickListener` for the "finish" button and the data was saved successfully.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my time, I had this scenario in recyclerview and was losing last editText value after click on button, becuase last editText focus didn't change and so onFocusChanged not called. I'd like to find a solution that make last editText would lose focus when outside it, same button click...and find your solution. It,s worked great!

Comment: this is my friend is the best answer for listview and for multiple edittext inside the list

Answer (score 4):

### In Kotlin

**hidekeyboard()** is a Kotlin Extension

```kotlin
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}
```

In activity add **dispatchTouchEvent**

```kotlin
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        val v: View? = currentFocus
        if (v is EditText) {
            val outRect = Rect()
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
            if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                v.clearFocus()
                hideKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Add these properties in the top most parent

```xml
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: What's the point of `hideKeyboard()` if the function is basically empty, then calls itself recursively forever (although I'll admit at the very least that argument will stop it from building, since `hideKeyboard()` has no parameters and one is being supplied, thus saving the user from the recursion)?

Comment: It depends on the model of the device that does not close the keyboard and must be hidden, another solution would be to check if the keyboard is visible to close once

Answer (score 3):

I really think it's a more robust way to use `getLocationOnScreen` than `getGlobalVisibleRect`. Because I meet a problem. There is a Listview which contain some Edittext and and set `ajustpan` in the activity. I find `getGlobalVisibleRect` return a value that looks like including the scrollY in it, but the event.getRawY is always by the screen. The below code works well.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if ( v instanceof EditText) {
            if (!isPointInsideView(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY(), v)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "!isPointInsideView");

                Log.i(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent clearFocus");
                v.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
}

/**
 * Determines if given points are inside view
 * @param x - x coordinate of point
 * @param y - y coordinate of point
 * @param view - view object to compare
 * @return true if the points are within view bounds, false otherwise
 */
private boolean isPointInsideView(float x, float y, View view) {
    int location[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int viewX = location[0];
    int viewY = location[1];

    Log.i(TAG, "location x: " + location[0] + ", y: " + location[1]);

    Log.i(TAG, "location xWidth: " + (viewX + view.getWidth()) + ", yHeight: " + (viewY + view.getHeight()));

    // point is inside view bounds
    return ((x > viewX && x < (viewX + view.getWidth())) &&
            (y > viewY && y < (viewY + view.getHeight())));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! It worked for all layout scenarios like RecyclerView, etc. etc. I tried other solution but this one fits all! :) Great job!

Answer (score 2):

Simply define two properties of parent of that `EditText` as :

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

So when user will touch outside of `EditText` area, focus will be removed because focus will be transferred to parent view.

Answer (score 1):

To lose the focus when other view is touched , both views should be set as view.focusableInTouchMode(true).

But it seems that use focuses in touch mode are not recommended.
Please take a look here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html

Comment: Yes, I have read this, but it's not exactly what I want. I don't need the other view to become focused. Although I don't see any alternative way right now... Maybe, somehow make the root view to capture focus when user clicks on non-focusable child?

Comment: As long as I know , the focus cannot be managed by a class, it is managed by android...no ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use the default method [`clearFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus())

You know how to solve codes in `onTouchListener` right?

Just call `EditText.clearFocus()`. It will clear focus in `last EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

As @pcans suggested you can do this overriding `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in your activity.

Here we get the touch coordinates and comparing them to view bounds. If touch is performed outside of a view then do something.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View yourView = (View) findViewById(R.id.view_id);
        if (yourView != null && yourView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // touch coordinates
            int touchX = (int) event.getX();
            int touchY = (int) event.getY();
            // get your view coordinates
            final int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
            yourView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);

            // The left coordinate of the view
            int viewX1 = viewLocation[0];
            // The right coordinate of the view
            int viewX2 = viewLocation[0] + yourView.getWidth();
            // The top coordinate of the view
            int viewY1 = viewLocation[1];
            // The bottom coordinate of the view
            int viewY2 = viewLocation[1] + yourView.getHeight();

            if (!((touchX >= viewX1 && touchX <= viewX2) && (touchY >= viewY1 && touchY <= viewY2))) {

                Do what you want...

                // If you don't want allow touch outside (for example, only hide keyboard or dismiss popup) 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Also it's not necessary to check view existance and visibility if your activity's layout doesn't change during runtime (e.g. you don't add fragments or replace/remove views from the layout). But if you want to close (or do something similiar) custom context menu (like in the Google Play Store when using overflow menu of the item) it's necessary to check view existance. Otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

This simple snippet of code does what you want

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                return true;
            }
        });
mScrollView.setOnTouchListener((v, e) -> gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

**A small improvement to the great solutions above**

This is basically a kotlin version of @zMan's solution with two improvements:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    hideSoftInputKeyboardIfRelevant(event)
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}

private fun hideSoftInputKeyboardIfRelevant(event: MotionEvent) {
    // not applicable for messaging user interfaces where keyboard should remain visible even after pressing the send button
    if (this is ContinuousInputInterface) return
    // hide keyboard after touch event ends (otherwise the keyboard hides and reappears quickly if the user clicks another EditText)
    if (event.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return
    //only if a view is currently focused
    currentFocus?.let { focusedView ->
        // applies only to EditText views
        if (focusedView !is EditText) return
        // only if the user is clicking outside the EditText view currently in focus
        val outRect = Rect()
        focusedView.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
        if (outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) return
        // if all conditions apply clear focus and hide keyboard
        focusedView.clearFocus()
        val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

it also includes the creation of an empty interface that works like a flag to extend some of your activities with

```
interface ContinuousInputInterface

class SomeMessagingActivity : 
   BaseActivityThatOverridesDispatchTouchEvent, ContinuousInputInterface { 
}
```

- this solution allows you to understand immediately what you are doing in `dispatchTouchEvent` and also manages to reduce indentations to just one.
- it also adds a custom exclusion for special activities such as Whatsapp-Style messaging activities where having the `EditText` lose focus and the keyboard hide on every click outside an `EditText` might be undesirable. It also allows you to reimplement `dispatchTouchEvent` from scratch on a child Activity by simply having that activity implement `ContinuousInputInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the answers here, I've created a lightweight `FrameLayout` that could be used to fulfill the requirement whilst keeping your codebase nice and DRY.

```kotlin
class FocusCleaningFrameLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val backgroundExecutor: Executor = /* ... */
    private val foregroundExecutor: Executor = /* ... */

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        backgroundExecutor.execute {
            if (event.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return@execute
            val focusedView = findFocus() ?: return@execute
            if (event.happenedWithin(focusedView.visibleBounds)) return@execute
            foregroundExecutor.execute { focusedView.clearFocus() }
            hideSoftInput(focusedView)
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun hideSoftInput(view: View) {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }

    private fun MotionEvent.happenedWithin(bounds: Rect): Boolean {
        return bounds.contains(rawX.toInt(), rawY.toInt())
    }

    private val View.visibleBounds: Rect get() {
        return Rect().apply { getGlobalVisibleRect(this) }
    }
}
```

The idea is that this is a very common a use-case which one might need to satisfy in multiple activities. While overriding `Activity#dispatchTouchEvent()` in each of such activities could work, you'll end up with repeating code.

Having this logic be encapsulated makes it easy to reuse. All you would need to do is to have `FocusCleaningFrameLayout` as the root layout in your activities and you'll be good to go.

```xml
<FocusCleaningFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Rest of your views goes here. -->

</FocusCleaningFrameLayout>
```

---

You might notice that `FocusCleaningFrameLayout` attempts to offload most of its logic onto a worker thread. Depending on your needs, this can be a bit overkill. Large view hierarchies would definitely benefit from having the [traversing](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java%3Bl=1249?q=findfocus&start=11) `View#findFocus()` be run off the Main thread. But you can choose to omit them should you're confident that you won't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I have combined the solution of @quealegriamasalegre with the idea to use GestureDetector to handle just clicks and not scrolls and added check so that click on other EditText keeps the keyboard on:

In Activity

```
private lateinit var gestureDetector: GestureDetector

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            hideKeyboardOnTapOutsideEditText(e)
            return false
        }
    })
    ....
}

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {       
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

And this extension function for better reusability

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboardOnTapOutsideEditText(ev: MotionEvent) {
    if (ev.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return
    // only if a view is currently focused
    currentFocus?.let { focusedView ->
        // applies only to EditText views
        if (focusedView !is EditText) return
        val x = ev.rawX.toInt()
        val y = ev.rawY.toInt()
        // only if the user is clicking outside the EditText view currently in focus
        val outRect = Rect()
        focusedView.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
        if (outRect.contains(x, y)) return
        // only if not another editText has been touched
        if (focusedView.rootView.touchables.filterIsInstance<EditText>    ().any { editText ->
            editText.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
            outRect.contains(x, y)
        }) return
        // if all conditions apply clear focus and close keyboard
        focusedView.clearFocus()
        hideKeyboard()
    }
}
```