# Change focus of edittext when tap outsite edittext

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have a edit text to input url, and a webview to display the website

My problem is: when i go google.com, i tap to my edit text so my edit text has focus.

I tap to search area in gooogle, but my edittext doen't lose focus.

How can can i change focus of edittext when tap outsite edittext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the answer from here: [EditText, clear focus on touch outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828636/edittext-clear-focus-on-touch-outside?rq=1)

and here:

[Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus?rq=1)

You can make cursor and focus disappear by

```
edittext.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score -2):

Do something on the line of

```
/**
 * hide soft keyboard
 */
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputManager != null)
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);       
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if(view == mWebView) {
        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer only hides the keyboard, but it doesn't change the focus of the EditText box.