# OnEditorActionListener not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I simply want to catch the event when the user press enter on an editText.

I did not get the Toast message, not the "Enter pressed" and not the "Some key pressed!" either.

What m i doing wrong?

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some key pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

E D I T :

**Well it is working on Android 2.3.3 and not working on 4.1.2**
Any ideas how can i make this work on any android device?

Comment: you can use TextWatcher for any events related to Edittext

Answer (score 29):

Please try to set the `EditText` in single line mode.

```
editText.setSingleLine();
```

or in your xml layout file:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

**UPDATE**

<strike>`android:singleLine="true"`</strike> is deprecated. From now on, use `android:maxLines="1"` with `android:inputType="text"` for achieving this behaviour

OR

```
editText.setMaxLines(1);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

for setting programmatically.

Comment: Also other input types will work (I think if they prevent the new line character) such as "textPersonName"

Comment: @CameronKetcham: that's true. "InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD" will also work

Comment: god you saved my day!

Comment: Not sure it this is old info but it is not working on my Nexus 6p with 7.1

Answer (score 3):

use `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` in xml. `actionDone` no longer responds to `onEditorAction`.

Answer (score 3):

`android:inputType="text"` and `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` do the wonder.

Answer (score 2):

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some key pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
    return false;
}
});
```

This code displays me **some key pressed** when pressed enter key after typing something in my edittext. But I don't know what is problem in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that I had set in XML `android:inputType="textMultiline"`. When I removed `textMultiline` option, the `EditorListener` started working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Atul Chatuverdi's answer was downvoted, -- after lots of browsing, this one finally did "a wonder" to me.

I confirm that ActionDone may not work. It works on my Samsung but for some reason doesn't work on Fly S. The event is just not fired. Both are Android 7.1. I wonder, if it is a bug of Google's keyboard...

The code that I used to make it finally work on all devices is

```
<EditText   
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:inputType="textUri"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:imeOptions="actionGo"          
     ...
     android:id="@+id/et_path"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

(You can use text instead of textUri, depending on your needs).

In my fragment:

```
editText = view.findViewById(R.id.et_path);
...
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new onGo());
```

and the nested class to process the action.

```
private class onGo implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

         // To do stuff
        return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
  }
```

As for `if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))` in a multiline text, I have the same problem. It works with Samsung keyboard, Hacker's keyboard, but not Google keyboard.

Advice to use a textwatcher is a no-go for various reasons (like pasting text with enter signs instead of pressing the enter button and others).