# OnEditorActionListener not working with Google keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to listen for "Enter" key in my `EditText` and it works using `OnEditorActionListener` on all keyboards except Google keyboard. I am using the code below:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {               
                    if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO | i == EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) {
                        // My code
                    } else if (keyEvent != null && keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        // My code
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Neither first condition nor second one works with Google keyboard. I also set this options for my `EditText`:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO | EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION);
```

I tried setting and listening for `ACTION_DONE`, `ACTION_GO`, `ACTION_NEXT` and so on. Can you help me fix the problem?

Comment: did you done all those https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901863/oneditoractionlistener-not-working?

Comment: @sasikumar Yes, I tried almost everything except setting setSingleLine(true), because I want my EditText to be expanded during the input.

Comment: without using `setSingleLine(true)` its not possible.