# How to Listen Android keyboard Close Event after Typing finished in EditText?

Tags: android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, android-keypad, android-event

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063439/android-edittext-finished-typing-event) to listen the android EditText finish typing event. But from this reference i am getting the **Enter** key pressed event only. I need to listen an event when user closes keybord after finishing the typing and also when user presses **Next**. is there any way to listen theses events in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i got the answer for Next/Done/search AND enter key press like this

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event !=null){
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || 
                actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || 
                actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || 
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && 
                event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {

                 Log.e("", "FINISHED Typing : "+v.getText().toString());
                   return true; // consume.
            }   
        }
    }
    else{
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            Log.e("", "Next/Done/Search Pressed");
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

also for the Keypad dismiss i customized the editText and override the method onKeyPreIme into that. Whenever i need the edittext , i am using this edittext. this solved my issue.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(event);
           //do whatever you want to do here, when keypad dismiss on EditText 
            return false;
        } 
    } 
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```