# EditText setOnKeyListener not working when value changes

Tags: android, android-edittext, return-value, keylistener, getview

Here's my code :

```
private EditText EditHal;
....
....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
layout = convertView;
if (convertView == null) {
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
}
EditHal = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.input_hal);
EditHal.setClickable(true);
EditHal.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
....
EditHal.setText("" + 1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //hardcoded at Here
EditHal.requestFocus();
EditHal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), EditHal.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
});
return layout;
}
```

And here is XML of my_fragment layout :

```
....
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_hal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="@string/hal"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

The issue :

on the code above, (EditText) EditHal value is "1".
But, if i changes the value of EditHal to the other number, and then i hit Enter/Done Key on the keyboard, the value of EditHal still "1", no changes at all.

I want that every time i changes the value inside EditHal field, and i hit Enter/Done Key, the Toast will show a number that i have input.
Please tell me how to solve it. 
Thanks

**Edited (solved)** :

I changes the code above with this :

```
//private EditText EditHal;
....
....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
layout = convertView;
if (convertView == null) {
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
}

//final added at EditText
final EditText EditHal = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.input_hal);  

EditHal.setClickable(true);
EditHal.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
....
EditHal.setText("" + 1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //hardcoded at Here
EditHal.requestFocus();
EditHal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), EditHal.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
});
return layout;
}
```

and the problem is gone. Thank you Jean Yang.

Comment: use this link for getting value when press enter or done
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063439/android-edittext-finished-typing-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because`EditText` does not know whether user finishes typing or not.

For example, you could add `android:singleLine="true"` of your `EditText` in xml file.

When you hit ENTER, the keyboard will close automatically and the toast shows up.
Android thinks that you finished typing and close the keyboard for you; otherwise, if you allow multi-line, Android catches ENTER KEY as a newline/line-break.

**EDIT**

Add `toString` method after `getText`

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), EditHal.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And since `EditHal` is being accessed within inner class, declare `EditHal` as a `final` variable.

```
final EditText EditHal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_hal);
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I just updated my question (xml file added). Please help.

Comment: did you use a special input keyboard?
for instance, i use HTC input, it won't "send" what you type to EditText until you click its suggestion or press ENTER.  This is, you have to double click enter.

Comment: I run the code on my Android phone (5.0) with SDK 23.  It is OK.

Comment: Or try add `.toString()` after `getText()`.  `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), EditHal.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: no, i didn't use special input, jus a number with default keyboard. Would you like to share your "OK" code?

Comment: i tried to add .toString() after getText(), and run this app. And i change EditHal field number from "1" to "2", but the Toast still show a number "1" after i press an enter key

Comment: Do you add `final` to your `EditText`?  Something like `final EditText EditHal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_hal);`  Tell me If it still doesn't work, and I'll edit my answer and paste my code

Comment: haha.. thanks, bro! you save my life. It's weird. Why after i add `final` on my `EditText` and the problem is solved when my code doesn't show any error at all? Thanks! :D

Comment: Your editor should give your a hint "Variable EditHal is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final" and it seems not.  You may update your Android Studio or your favorite IDE :P

Comment: I don't see why it should matter if the user has "finished typing". The title specifically asks about detecting when the value changes, ie after each keystroke.