# Edit text Onclick and Keyboard action event

Tags: android

I want to Edit Text but only on **onClick** event and soon as it finishes the cursor ***visibility*** should be ***false*** again like before. Only onClick event would ***show*** cursor and editing ***enable*** as soon as done typing and press keyboard action button it should make the cursor visibility ***false*** again

**Here is Xml part**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/pname"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileimg"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/nickname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

**This is Coding part:**

```
pname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pname);

pname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         pname.setInputType(0x0000006);
         pname.setCursorVisible(true);
     }
});
/*pname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
         if(hasFocus){
             pname.setCursorVisible(false);
         } else {
             pname.setCursorVisible(false);
         }
     }
});
*/

pname.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || actionId ==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
                pname.setCursorVisible(false);
                return true; // consume.
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Problem/Error:** It seems as soon as I am done typing and press keyboard action done key my activity stops working unfortunately

**Exception:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getKeyCode()' on a null object reference at packagename.MainActivity$2.onEditorAction(MainActivity.java:‌​69) line no 69

Comment: _activity stops working unfortunately_ Is there an exception ? I am not sure I understand those explication. PLease try to explain this a but more.

Comment: @AxelH java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getKeyCode()' on a null object reference at packagename.MainActivity$2.onEditorAction(MainActivity.java:69)

line no 69 is "If" Condition and The problem I wrote is the pop up i am getting in my android mobile screen Unfortunately your app stop working Got it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @AxelH Wow Brilliant ! I am asking where I am getting null value and why when I am editting text into it. First read properly and then answer I know this is a null pointer exception but in my CASE WHERE?????

Comment: @AxelH Seriously! I know but why ???? I know Its not taking my action key but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the `KeyEvent` received but the doc prevent you :

> KeyEvent: If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null.

So you need to check if this is not `null` to prevent exception.

Here is the [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html#onEditorAction(android.widget.TextView,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

Comment: I dont know see this I have used a code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063439/android-edittext-finished-typing-event

Comment: But you check first the key, not the action. Maybe the event is only null if `actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`. Meaning that this is doing this check like this. But that is not the point. The doc tell you it can be `null`, you get a `NullPointerException` ... so just check if it is `null` to prevent that. You can always see when it is happening to understand but that is not the point here

Comment: Yeah I put a breakline and debug the app event is coming null now tell me how to fix it

Comment: Ok thanks I got it Let me try if done then come back and verify your answer thanks

Comment: OK did it but after action done button clicked its not going down again like it was happenning previously

Comment: @SameerKhan1406 This is not clear, please try to explain the problem better. What is that mean _not going down again_  ? Your requirements are not clear from the beginning...

Comment: Keyboard is not going going down as soon as I am finish typing and tapping 
Action Button
I put this condition : 

if (event!=null && event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || actionId != EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ) {
                    return false;
                }
then : else if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event==null || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)

Comment: @SameerKhan1406 That is the first time you are talking about hidding the vitrual keyboard here. For this, simply look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130091/discussion-between-sameerkhan1406-and-axelh).

Comment: Follow up Discussion Please