# Pass data from fragments to activity when changing fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm needing a way to pass data from multiple fragments to an activity. This data can only be sent to the activity when I change the fragment tab.
To pass the data I am using the interface method, but I do not know in which function of the class fragment I can put the method that will take the text of the EditText and send to the activity through the interface.

Comment: Its only when you switch fragments, right?
You could place the code in the onDetach()

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to pass the data only when the fragment changes?  If not, you could add a callback to the edit text that calls the interface method your activity implements.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8063840/9154960) has some good examples on how to do that.

Comment: Another way would be to fill all 10 fragments, and then send the 10 data to an object. And to send this data would be to push a button in the activity