# How to know when a user is done typing?

Tags: java, android, textview, editview

In Android Studio, I want to make a program where a `TextView` changes to an `EditView` when clicked. After the user is finished typing, I want the `EditText` to then change back to a `TextView` which shows the value that was entered.

How do I do this? This is what I have so far:

```
loc > TextView, 
edit_loc > EditText

loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        loc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edit_loc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you simple edit text view and set it clickable false when user complete the typing .. for know when user is typing or not you use this code:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        //when user is typing
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
         // after user complete typing
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding @amit-pandey, it's not the complete solution because after each typing the `TextWatcher` being called

check this link, it is better solution but it's not the best

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625726/12177115