# How to clear focus for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an activity with a search box (`EditText`) on the top, and a ListView below. Whenever the activity starts, the EditText always has focus and bring up the keyboard which partially cover the `ListView`.

There's no other text view that can have focus.
I want the EditText to have focus ONLY when the user touches it and start typing. I try to put `clearFocus()` in `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated` or `onCreated`, but no luck.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Set in your parent layout next attributes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

And now, when `activity` starts this layout getting default focus.

Also we can remove focus from children views in runtime (e.g. after finishing child editing):

```
findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).requestFocus();
```

or

Look in the AndroidManifest.xml  element.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

It always hide key board when entering the activity.

Comment: So many good & quick answer, but this one is the simplest to me. Tks all

Comment: I've tried SO MANY other suggested solutions to this problem and THIS is the which WORKS!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: For me android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" works as I have many edit text in that screen.I have to clear focus from all edit text and request focus to another view .But thanks for this reference .

Comment: Thanks for `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`. It was just what I needed.

Comment: absolutely lovely

Answer (score 6):

You could use set focus on container view. Add to container **android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**, **android:focusable="true"** and tag **requestFocus** example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <requestFocus/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

you must have mentioned `<requestFocus>` tag in your `editTiext field` in XML remove that and run again

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

where ever you want to clear focus.

Comment: this will not work if you have multi editText in a view, this is just an example that will break this approach, I also have to mention that behaviour is different in different phones, but I can see that this solution has some problems

Answer (score 2):

Add the android:focusable="true" and  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" elements in the parent layout of EditText as follow;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

I think, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer [EditText, clear focus on touch outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828636/edittext-clear-focus-on-touch-outside).

Or you can just write widget which will show only text with textView and `onClick`will display dialog with `EditText` where you can edit this text/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

On your `Activity` Declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml` add the below code :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

It will prevent the keyboard to popup up when activity becomes visible.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score -3):

This will do your work:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`