# Hiding soft keyboard without having focus

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am using a `FrameLayout` to show an `EditText` and a `ListView` (with checkboxes) alternately. When showing an `EditText`, I would like the soft keyboard to be shown. And when showing the `ListView`, I would like the soft keyboard to be hidden. Now usually a focus is needed in order to hide the soft keyboard. When my `ListView` gets shown, then `getCurrentFocus()` returns `null`. Is there a way to hide the soft keyboard, without having a focus?

I am showing the soft keyboard like that:

```
public static void requestFocusAndMoveCursorToTheEndAndShowKeyboard(final EditText editTextParam, final Activity activityParam) {
    if (editTextParam == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (editTextParam.requestFocus()) {
        editTextParam.setSelection(editTextParam.getText().length()); // move Cursor to the end of the EditText
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activityParam.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
}
```

And I am trying to hide the soft keyboard like that:

```
public static void hideSoftInputKeyboardFromWindow(Activity activityParam) {
    if (activityParam == null) {
        return;
    }

    View view = activityParam.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activityParam.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [.clearFocus();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus%28%29) on edittext when you don't want a focus on it.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidMenifest.xml add this:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Write following method to youractivity or to your utility class

```
/**
 * Hide soft keypad
 * 
 */


public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity, View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `hideSoftInputKeyboardFromWindow` method, try:

```
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

instead of

```
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Edit: ok same answer as Dorami

Answer (score 0):

How do you show them alternately? Using different fragments? Or do you simply inflate different layouts? Provide more details with your complete code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Finally I got it solved using a View.OnFocusChangeListener for the EditText, like described here:

[Hide soft keyboard on losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412943/hide-soft-keyboard-on-losing-focus)