# Is there an equivalent for dispatchTouchEvent() from Activity in Dialog or DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, touch-event, android-dialogfragment

I need to intercept all touch events in the application to monitor for a custom activity time out.

Currently I use `dispatchTouchEvent()` in my activities but this is not called if I have a dialog on the screen. Does any one know if there any way I can have this same functionality with a dialog being present?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get a answer to this?

Comment: Nope never did, but I am not working on the project any more.

Comment: @draksia @Jailbroken I did try this I called `dispatchTouchEvent()` on the `Activity` from the `Dialog`'s `dispatchTouchEvent()`. However implementing this turned a little nasty for me since I found that this does not work for `ListView` and `GridView`'s `OnItemClickListener` i.e. you don't get any callbacks (Only on some devices). All the other views and layouts worked fine though!

Comment: Any solution for this issue @Abbas

Answer (score 9):

For use `dispatchTouchEvent()` in DialogFragment, override `onCreateDialog` and return a custom `Dialog` with `dispatchTouchEvent` (in your custom DialogFragment).

Exemple, for dismiss keyboard when click outside in DialogFragment:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()) {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy a Kotlin version everyone:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return object : Dialog(requireContext()){
            override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                // do your thing here
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
            }
        }
    }

}
```