# Keyboard only appears when user clicks on EditText

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, keyboard

I have the following `xml` file in my `android app`. When user opens the app, the keyboard becomes active at the same time. Even though user has not even started in the `EditText`.

How could I control keyboard? I want keyboard to appear when a user tap on the `EditText`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mList"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
    <EditText
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search" />
   <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/mListView" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `axml` file as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mWellList"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

or do it with code:

```
var root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mWellList);
root.RequestFocus();
```

as described here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1856/how-to-disable-auto-focus-on-edit-text

**To hide the Keyboard:**

Include:

```
 using Android.Views.InputMethods;
```

and then:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService); 
imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(YourEditTextHere.WindowToken, 0);
```

Also check this thread for clearing focus on touch outside: [EditText, clear focus on touch outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828636/edittext-clear-focus-on-touch-outside/8766475#8766475)

Comment: Ok that works perfectly fine. In my example, I have `ListView` and `EditText`. Lets assume that user click on `Edittext` and keyboard focus and then user change his mind not to type anything. How you dismiss keyboard? By the way I have marked your answer and upvoted.

Comment: Thanks CDRosos, but I am getting the following error the `GetSystemService is not in the current context`

Comment: I have edit the code, try again please. Are you using fragments or Activity?

Comment: I am still having the same issue, I am using fragments

Comment: try with this: InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);

inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);

Answer (score 0):

Add in the **manifest** file inside the **activity** tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

like Below

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: where should I put it ? In my `EditText` property?

Comment: I am using `Xamarin.Android`, There is no `activity` tag inside the manifest file.