# AppCompatEditText focus Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have long form (LinearLayout as root) which consist of EditTexts and TextView. 
**Now Issue i am facing is** : After clicking the Edit Text, if i clicking on textviews then the focus of an edit text is not clearing. Hence, screen scroll to that edit text due to focus.

**I have tried solution - android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in parent layout but no luck.**

[image]

**I have attached an image showing an issue. I have clicked on consulting doctor field which is a TextView but focus is till on email Edit text.**

> Please help me with some solution. Thanks.

Comment: put textview in focusable in touch mode

Comment: @JaydeepPatel tried. not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28939113/3467204 is it what you want?

Comment: @WannaBeGeek tried this one as well , what happening is, edit cursor moving up and down on screen scroll up and down

Answer (score 0):

> After clicking the Edit Text, if i clicking on textviews then the focus of an edit text is not clearing. Hence, screen scroll to that edit text due to focus.

Wrap your EditText inside FrameLayout as shown below

```
<FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But there are more than one editext and texview (Like form) in random manner. If i wrap every editText inside frame layout than it would make layout mess up. what say?

Comment: Yes, You need to wrap up every EditText individually.

Answer (score 0):

public static void hideSoftKeyboard (View view)

{

```
InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

}

//Call this method on textview click