# Best way to unfocus edittext when user interacts with another (non-texual) input element

Tags: android, checkbox, textbox, focus, user-input

I have an activity with some edittexts and some checkboxes, etc.

I have validators set on text entries that get executed when a text entry loses focus. But the problem is when the user clicks/touches a checkbox, edittext doesn't lose focus and therefore the validator is not run.

What is the best way for causing unfocus of text entries when the user touches another input field? I know I can e.g. set a handler on every checkbox to force unfocusing of text fields happen, but I think there is probably a more concise/general method for this purpose; Setting a handler on every checkbox seems too cumbersome and error prone.

thank u.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: You may want to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828636/edittext-clear-focus-on-touch-outside).

Comment: hooray! this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43828004/2982512

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way(it only is an example).

**your_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sv_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EditText 1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EditText 2" />

        ..............other views................

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Using `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the `LinearLayout` to make the `EditText` is focused when touching on it( or when starting this activity there is not auto focus to any `EditText` also).

**In your activity:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        ScrollView svContent = findViewById(R.id.sv_content);
        svContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int action  = motionEvent.getAction();

                if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    View focusView = getCurrentFocus();
                    if (focusView != null) {
                        // The code for unfocus here

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tested your code. Unfortunately, OnTouchListener is not called when I click on a checkbox directly; but it is called when i click on an empty place within my layout.