# How to keep Android activity from auto-focusing on EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I've got an issue with an EditText view automatically receiving focus *not* on activity launch, but once another EditText within the activity has been edited. And once that first EditText has focus, it won't let go. The extremely odd thing is that I have only seen this behavior when I am testing on Android v8 (API 26). On v10 (API 29), my program works just fine.

I've tried basically everything except the invisible overlay that's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828636/edittext-clear-focus-on-touch-outside), and again - it all works fine in later Android versions. I'm just noticing this behavior in v8. If anyone has an idea of how to fix this - or if this is a consequence of old tech, I'd appreciate you letting me know!

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_project_question_root"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_three_fourths"
            style="@style/H2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:background="@color/ccc_gray"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close_btn" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/zero_dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_container"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/save_btn_divider"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_3"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Headline.32"
                android:text="@string/header"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@idtoolbar_container"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_2"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/answer_questions_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_1_5"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                android:background="@drawable/gray_rounded_rectangle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/answer_questions_header"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/zero_dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/light_bulb_iv"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_half"
                    style="@style/Body.16"
                    android:text="@string/warning" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/light_bulb_iv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_light_bulb_icon" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

// EditTexts are part of items within the RecyclerView

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/qa_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_one_fourth"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questions_container"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

// File continues on but nothing should be relevant
```

**Activity.kt file**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Activity : SMBaseActivity(BottomNavigationView2020.State.HIDE_NAVBAR), ProjectQuestionsContract.View {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: Contract.Presenter
    lateinit var BookingProjectDetailsAdapter: Adapter
    private var saveChangesDialog: PopupView? = null
    private var fragment: QADropdownChooserFragment = QADropdownChooserFragment()
    private var editable: Boolean = false
    private var isSaveActive: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        val BookingDetailsViewObject = intent.getParcelableExtra<BookingDetailsViewObject>(BOOKING_DETAILS_VIEW_OBJECT_KEY)
            ?: throw NullPointerException("")

        close_btn.setOnClickListener { presenter.onClosePressed(isSaveActive) }
        save_btn.isEnabled = false
        save_btn.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.onSavePressed()
        }

        editable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_EDITABLE_KEY, false)
        if (editable){
            delete_btn.setOnClickListener { presenter.onDeletePressed() }
            delete_btn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        showQuestions(BookingDetailsViewObject, false)
        presenter.onViewCreated(this, BookingDetailsViewObject)
    }

    override fun onStart(){
        super.onStart()
        presenter.onStart()
    }

    override fun getContentViewLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_project_questions
    }

    override fun showLoading(show: Boolean){
        showLoadingDialog(R.string.loading)
    }

    override fun stopLoadingSpinner(stayOnPage: Boolean) {
        stopLoadingSpinner(save_btn, stayOnPage)
    }

    override fun startLoadingSpinner() {
        startLoadingSpinner(save_btn)
    }

    override fun showNetworkError(throwable: Throwable, tryAgain: (() -> Unit)?, dismiss: (() -> Unit)?, serverErrorTextResId: Int, clientErrorTextResId: Int): Boolean {
        return handleNetworkError(throwable, tryAgain, dismiss, getString(serverErrorTextResId), getString(clientErrorTextResId))
    }

    override fun showQuestions(BookingDetailsViewObject: BookingDetailsViewObject, loading: Boolean) {
        BookingProjectDetailsAdapter = ProjectQuestionsAdapter(BookingDetailsViewObject.getFilteredQuestionsAndAnswers(), loading, customerQACallbacks, context, ManagerFactory.getInstance().schedulerProvider)
        qa_rv.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = BookingProjectDetailsAdapter
            isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
        }
    }

    override fun closeActivityAfterSaving() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        finish()
    }

    override fun closeActivityAfterDeleting() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent().putExtra(DELETE_FLAG, true ))
        finish()
    }

    override fun closeActivityWithoutSaving(){
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        finish()
    }

    override fun showSaveChangesModal() {
        saveChangesDialog = PopupView.showViewAsPopupWithBlurBackground(this.window.decorView, R.layout.dialog_save_changes_to_project, closeOnBackgroundClick = false, viewInflatedListener = { view ->

            val headerText: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_save_changes_to_project_header)
            headerText.text = resources.getString(R.string.save_changes)

            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_save_button).setOnClickListener {
                presenter.onSaveModalSavePressed()
            }

            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialog_dont_save_button).setOnClickListener {
                presenter.onSaveModalDoNotSavePressed()
            }

            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_cancel_tv).setOnClickListener {
                presenter.onSaveModalCancelPressed()
            }
        }, useFadeTransition = true)
    }

    override fun dismissSaveModal() {
        saveChangesDialog?.popupWindow?.dismiss()
        saveChangesDialog = null
    }

    override fun displayDeleteModal() {
        showHAAlert(
            getString(R.string.delete_modal),
            "",
            getString(R.string.button_delete),
            getString(R.string.cancel_button),
            { presenter.onQADeletePressed() },
            { presenter.onQACancelPressed() },
            false
        )
    }

    override fun dismissDeleteModal() {
        super.unblockUi()
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val v = currentFocus
            if (v is EditText) {
                val outRect = Rect()
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
                if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                    v.clearFocus()
                    val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0)
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun enableSave(answersHaveChanged: Boolean) {
        if (answersHaveChanged){
            save_btn.isActivated = true
            save_btn.isEnabled = true
            isSaveActive = true
        } else {
            save_btn.isActivated = false
            save_btn.isEnabled = false
            isSaveActive = false
        }
    }

    private val customerQACallbacks = object : Adapter.CustomerQAClickListener {
        override fun onTextQuestionResponseChanged(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?, textBoxText: String) {
            presenter.onTextQuestionResponseChanged(question, textBoxText)
        }

        override fun onMultiOptionsUpdated(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?, selectedAnswersList: MutableList<Int?>) {
            presenter.onMultiSelectionChanged(question, selectedAnswersList)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val BOOKING_DETAILS_VIEW_OBJECT_KEY = "BOOKING_KEY"
        const val IS_EDITABLE_KEY = "IS_EDITABLE"
        const val DELETE_FLAG = "DELETE_FLAG"

        @JvmStatic
        fun newIntent(context: Context, BookingDetailsViewObject: BookingDetailsViewObject, editable: Boolean) : Intent {
            return Intent(context, ProjectQuestionsActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(BOOKING_DETAILS_VIEW_OBJECT_KEY, BookingDetailsViewObject)
                putExtra(IS_EDITABLE_KEY, editable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RV Adapter**

```
class Adapter(
    val projectQuestions: List<BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto>?,
    val loading: Boolean,
    val callbacks: CustomerQAClickListener,
    val context: Context,
    val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.BookingProjectDetailsViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): BookingProjectDetailsViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return when (viewType) {
            TEXT_AREA_SUBTYPE -> {
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fpp_customer_qa_text_box, parent, false)
                TextAreaQAViewHolder(view)
            }
            MULTI_CHOICE_SUBTYPE -> {
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fpp_customer_qa_multi_select, parent, false)
                MultiChoiceQAViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> {
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fpp_customer_qa_text_box, parent, false)
                TextAreaQAViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookingProjectDetailsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val question = projectQuestions?.getOrNull(position)
        val isLast = (position == projectQuestions?.lastIndex)
        holder.bindQuestion(question, position, isLast)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return projectQuestions?.size ?: 0
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val current = projectQuestions?.getOrNull(position)
        return when (current?.getQuestionSubtype()) {
            QuestionSubType.TEXT_AREA -> TEXT_AREA_SUBTYPE
            QuestionSubType.MULTI_CHOICE -> MULTI_CHOICE_SUBTYPE
            else -> TEXT_AREA_SUBTYPE
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TEXT_AREA_SUBTYPE = 1
        private const val MULTI_CHOICE_SUBTYPE = 2
        private const val PLEASE_SELECT = "Please select"
    }

    abstract class BookingProjectDetailsViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val questionLabel: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_label)
        private val questionNumber: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_number)

        fun bindQuestion(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?, position: Int, isLast: Boolean) {
            questionLabel.text = question?.question?.label
            questionNumber.text = (position + 1).toString().plus(".")

            if (isLast) {
                itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.question_divider).visibility = View.GONE
            }

            bindQuestionTypeSpecificViews(question)
        }

        abstract fun bindQuestionTypeSpecificViews(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?)
    }

    inner class TextAreaQAViewHolder(view: View) :
        Adapter.BookingProjectDetailsViewHolder(view) {
        override fun bindQuestionTypeSpecificViews(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?) {
            val textBox = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.free_response_question_comment)
            val textResponse = question?.response?.text

            if (textResponse.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                textBox.setText("")
            } else {
                textBox.setText(textResponse)
                textBox.isActivated = true
            }

            textBox.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    callbacks.onTextQuestionResponseChanged(question, textBox.text.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class MultiChoiceQAViewHolder(view: View) :
        Adapter.BookingProjectDetailsViewHolder(view) {

        lateinit var selectedAnswersHolder: MultiChoiceQAAnswerHolder
        lateinit var otherTextBox: EditText

        override fun bindQuestionTypeSpecificViews(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?) {
            selectedAnswersHolder = MultiChoiceQAAnswerHolder(question)
            otherTextBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.multi_select_free_response_question_comment)

            question?.response?.text?.let {
                otherTextBox.setText(it)
                otherTextBox.isActivated = true
            }

            val MultiSelectAdapter = MultiSelectAdapter(question, context, ::textBoxEnabledCallback, ::multiSelectQuestionCallback)
            val multiSelectRV = itemView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.multi_select_rv)
            multiSelectRV.apply {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
                adapter = ProjectQuestionsMultiSelectAdapter
                isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
            }
        }

        private fun multiSelectQuestionCallback(id: Int?, addToList: Boolean) {
            if (addToList){
                selectedAnswersHolder.setSelectedAnswers(id)
            } else {
                selectedAnswersHolder.removeSelectedAnswers(id)
            }
        }

        private fun textBoxEnabledCallback(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?) {
            otherTextBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            otherTextBox.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    callbacks.onTextQuestionResponseChanged(question, otherTextBox.text.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class MultiChoiceQAAnswerHolder(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?) {
        val question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto? = question
        private var selectedAnswersList = question?.response?.optionIds ?: mutableListOf()

        fun setSelectedAnswers(selectedAnswer: Int?) {
            selectedAnswersList.add(selectedAnswer)
            callbacks.onMultiOptionsUpdated(question, selectedAnswersList)
        }

        fun removeSelectedAnswers(selectedAnswer: Int?){
            selectedAnswersList.remove(selectedAnswer)
            callbacks.onMultiOptionsUpdated(question, selectedAnswersList)
        }

        fun getSelectedAnswers(): MutableList<Int?>{
            return selectedAnswersList
        }
    }

    interface CustomerQAClickListener {
        fun onQADropdownQuestionClicked(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?)
        fun onTextQuestionResponseChanged(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?, textBoxText: String)
        fun onMultiOptionsUpdated(question: BookingSurveyQuestionAndResponseDto?, selectedAnswersList: MutableList<Int?>)    }
}
```

I'm including just one of the layout files containing the EditView, but if you need more, let me know.
**fpp_customer_qa_multi_select.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_1_5">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/multi_select_question_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/question_label"
            tools:text="4."
            style="@style/Headline.16"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_label"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/zero_dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_three_fourths"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/question_number"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="Why don't you tell me about the job that you are choosing to pursue"
            style="@style/Headline.16"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/multi_select_reminder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:text="@string/project_questions_multi_select"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Label2MiddleGray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/multi_select_question_header"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/multi_select_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_15dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_1_5"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_15dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/multi_select_reminder" />

// The section that's causing problems
    <controls.EditTextWithKeyboardEvents
        android:id="@+id/multi_select_free_response_question_comment"
        style="@style/Label1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:background="@drawable/fpp_text_area_background"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_1_5"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_15dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_1_5"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_15dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/blue_cursor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/multi_select_rv" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/question_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_1"
        android:background="@color/ccc_gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/free_response_question_comment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Clicking in a certain area of the screen will loose the focus of the first EditText.. In this instance, it's the EditText of the multichoice activity

Comment: I've got 2 duplicate DecorViews in the V8 layout inspector, and only 1 FrameLayout for my V10 layout inspector