# How to hide the soft keypad when leaving an editbox?

Tags: android

After a user inputs into an editbox with the keypad, I want the keypad to hide so I can see the results near the bottom of the screen. I've tried this in my onCreate method but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
InputMethodManager imm =                                  
      (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditTextbox.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what currently has focus...if its another editText that takes focus then this might be bringing up the keypad...try to explicitly give focus to a different element...

Comment: That was it, as i lost focus on the edittext box my code shown above hid the keypad, but the focus was directed to the next edittext box which opened the keypad against my will. To solve, I put in two commands to hide the keypad, one for the edittext box i left, and one for the editbox i just focused: 
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText1.getWindowToken(), 0); imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 3):

You can force hide the keyboard like so:

```
Window window = getWindow();
                window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I would get the window in your onCreate method and in the onFocusChanged() method or OnKeyListener() hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up a Key Listener?

You don't really state how you know the user is done entering the text so I'll assume they are pressing the enter button on the soft keyboard.  Here is how I am handling that type of scenario.  I am using this both in a Dialog and an Activity with success.  Hope it helps.

```
this.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
     /**
      * This listens for the user to press the enter button on 
      * the keyboard and then hides the virtual keyboard
      */
     @Override
     public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
     {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) &&
             (keyCode           == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)   )
        {               
           // hide virtual keyboard
           InputMethodManager imm = 
              (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(sessionTag.getWindowToken(), 0);
           return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `EditText` class and use your code in `onFocusChanged()` method when `focused` argument is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer. call the method after you setContentView in your activity.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656129/1066839