# how to hide keypad when click outside editText?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

i have custom `listview` with `editText` and edit the `edittext` data on tapping `edittext` with help of showing keypad it is working fine .

my problem is when i click outside of `edittext` the keypad must hide.

thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you have to take the onTouchListener on the parent layout of the Layout File. on the TouchListener you have to code to hide the Keyboard when click outside the EditText. Please follow XML Layout and Java class to resolve this issue please follow following url.

http://amitthaperandroidquery.blogspot.com/2011/10/remove-keyboard-after-click-outside.html

Comment: If you want more help then please query into my given blog url or post comment here.

Answer (score 2):

One way is that you can set a focus change listener to the EditText.
When the widget loses focus you can hide the Keyborad by:-

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     

     Log.d("onChange", "focus==" + hasFocus);
}});

Comment: when i click outside edittext like listview then it doesn't response

Comment: edittext will not change focus when clicking outside of it with setOnFocusChangeListener. It will only work when changing focus to something else that's focusable, like another edittext.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing the following steps:

1. Make the parent view(content view of your activity) clickable and focusable by adding the following attributes

   ```
       android:clickable="true" 
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   ```
2. Implement a hideKeyboard() method

   ```
       public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
           InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
       }
   ```
3. Lastly, set the onFocusChangeListener of your edittext.

   ```
       edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
               if (!hasFocus) {
                   hideKeyboard(v);
               }
           }
       });
   ```

From [This source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828165/609782)

Answer (score 0):

Another way similar to the accepted answer is to subclass the root view of the layout and override OnInterceptTouchEvent, hide the keyboard and return false to allow the touch to propagate as usual.

The example below is for Xamarin but it is easy to port to Java:

```
public class KeyboardHidingScrollView : ScrollView
{
    public KeyboardHidingScrollView (Context context) : base (context)
    {
    }

    public KeyboardHidingScrollView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent ev)
    {
        var methodManager = (InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService (Context.InputMethodService);
        methodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow (WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        return false;
    } 
}
```