# this.getFields() not recognized - what do I have to include?

Tags: android

I wanted to try the solution posted by htafoya here: [How to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext/7771606#7771606)

However

```
this.getFields();
```

is not recognized. What do I have to include or change so getFields is known?

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you're doing, but the question is so vague that I can't understand what you're getting at here. Please post a more in depth question, what exactly you're solving with the solution you're "trying", etc... help us help you.

Comment: There is nothing you can do if the current class does not include that method. Java is not like C where you can `#include` more files to provide more functions.

Comment: What is `this` dose it have a `getFields()` method?

Comment: More information is needed if you want to get a useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the accepted answer (to the question you link to)...

> I also finished by creating a method to get all the editTexts per view

In short, the OP of that question created a method in his/her `Activity` called `getFields()` which returns an array of all `EditText` objects in the `Activity`. This can be understood from the quote I post above and from this line in the code he/she posted...

```
EditText[] textFields = this.getFields();
```

You will need to define your own method to create / return an `EditText` array in order for the solution to work.