# How to add to an array elements with different ids

Tags: java, android

Sorry if the title wasn't clear enought, but what I'm trying to do is this:

In the xml I have a lot of `EditText` fields with different ids but almost the same(e.g. A1, A2, A3 etc.). What I'm trying to do is to add the values from those ids in an array with a loop.

```
EditText[] rEdit = new EditText[25];

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    rEdit[i] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A1);
}
```

How can I do it, so it will iterate through the ids too?

Comment: As a suggestion, I would recommend removing the `android-studio` tag. This is a problem with your code and not with the IDE so you would have this problem no matter what IDE you are using.

Comment: As per my knowledge , A Big No , you can't do this in loop

Comment: I ran in a similar issue and this helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8008659/6470431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `View`s have their IDs like `yourViewName0`, `yourViewName1`, `yourViewName2` etc.

You could do something like this:

```
EditText[] rEdit = new EditText[25];

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(getResources()
        .getIdentifier("yourViewName" + i, "id", getPackageName()));
    rEdit[i] = editText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of id's in `res/values/arrays.`

Load it via `getResources().getIntArray()`

Iterate it as usual

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
EditText[] rEdit = new EditText[25];

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("A"+i, "id", getPackageName());
    rEdit[i] = (EditText) findViewById(resId);
}
```

`resId`will get the A1, A2, A3...A24 ids and you can get the EditText easily as you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this for the same.

```
EditText[] rEdit = new EditText[25];
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
String edtvId="A"+i;
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(edtvId, "id",  "your_package_name");
 rEdit[i] = (EditText) findViewById(resID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with the ids first and then iterate over it:

```
int [] ids = new int[] {R.id.A1, R.id.A2, R.id.R3};

int n = 0;
for (int id : ids) {
    rEdit[n++] = (EditText)findViewById(id);
}
```