# How to get layout object

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I'm following the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790487/method-to-get-all-edittexts-in-a-view):

```
ArrayList<EditText> myEditTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++ )
  if( myLayout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof EditText )
    myEditTextList.add( (EditText) myLayout.getChildAt( i ) );
```

How do you get `myLayout`, what does it actually represent? In my app I define linear_layout in activitymain.xml but can't seem to get it in MainActivity.java (I tried using R but it didn't work). I'm new to Android development and could really use some high level guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let Linear Layout be the root of your xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/my_layout" >
   //your views goes here
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Activity you'll have to initialize the view once your layout gets inflated like this

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Why does it work like this? Why must it be initialized in the activity if it's already in the XML?

Comment: @northerner You are not initializing the Layout in the activity. Initialization looks like this `LinearLayout mLinearLayout  = new LinearLayout();` the method `findViewById()` just gives the reference to the View which has already been initialized because you wrote it in XML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `myLayout` as your root layout in your `layout.xml` file

the `myLayout` maybe a **`FrameLayout`**, **`LinearLayout`**, **`RelativeLayout`** or **`ConstraintLayout`** layout

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- add your view here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Now do `findViewById` in side your actvity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout myLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        myLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    }


}
```

Comment: may i know the good reason for down vote so i  can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get a reference of your `LinearLayout` in Java code.

`LinearLayout myLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout_id)`

Answer (score 0):

assuming your actiivtymain.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeLayout
 android:id="@+id/some_id"
...>
 <EditText
...
/>

<EditText
...
/>
.
.
.
</SomeLayout>
```

`mLayout` you are referring is the parent of all your edit texts. It may not be the root of your layout but if you want to get a Java instance of it, you need to give it an id. and get the instance by using the code given by @Nilesh Rathod. One more thing to remember is to call the method `findViewById(R.id.my_layout);` only after `setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);`.