# How to Hide virtual keyboard when clicking out side in Android

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext) tutorial.

The code is working fine for one `editText`. But now I have many (nearly 10) `EditText` fields. If I repeat this code for every field, the code will be lengthy. Can anybody let me know how to disable a virtual keyboard when click outside of any field?

Comment: It's native, you dont need to do nothing to get this behaviour. The keyboard just show yourself when focused in a EditText, but when you leave it, the keyboard become invisible. Just make sure which none edit text are focused.

Comment: The answer on question which you used as tutorial contains exact answer on your question. getFields() method return not single EditText field but all fields from activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
View view = getCurrentFocus();
boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

if (view instanceof EditText) {
    View w = getCurrentFocus();
    int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
    w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
    float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
    float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
&& (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() 
|| y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

May be this will help you.. check it

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Simply use this code to hide the keyboard inside the onTouchDown() method of an OnTouchListener that is tied to the parent layout.

Hope this will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Comment: check by, replace 'stateHidden' by 'adjustResize' or 'adjustPan'

Comment: I have tried all of [these](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode)  but no use