# android : hide virtual keyboard when the edittext is not clickable and not enabled

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have a checkbox on whose de-selection i enable my edittext field (mEditText.setClickable(true) and mEditText.setEnabled(true) )

but, when these two fields are false i.e when the check box is selected--->>> when i click on my disabled Edittext field it shows a Virtual keyboard, though the edittext field is not edittable.

i want a fix to this problem

When i tried mEdittext.setfocusable(false) when checkbox deselected and setfocusable(true) when checkbox selected.... the field become non editable and the virtal keyboard also doesnot appear at all

Comment: Have you tried  `mEdittext..setEnabled(false);`?

Comment: yeah have tried that aswell.....infact have tried everything but not the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i getting form your question.

```
cb = check Box
Edit_Text = Edit Text

 if (!cb.isChecked())
        {
          Edit_Text.setEnabled(true);
          Edit_Text.setClickable(true);
        }
        else
        {
          Edit_Text.setEnabled(false);
          Edit_Text.setClickable(false);
        }
```

For Hide the KeyBoard you should refer this :

[How to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext)

Comment: yeah this is current the scenario..how to force the virtual keyboard not to pop up when (!checked)