# Issue with scrolling, virtual keyboard and theme: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, keyboard, scroll, themes

I have an ExpandableListView with EditTexts in it. If user tries to scroll when the virtual keyboard is up I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
```

I tried to find a solution to this problem, someone suggested removing the theme. Well, it solves the problem with the crash, but this time I am not able to edit the EditText. Virtual keyboard appears (in low-case letters even though I have `android:capitalize="characters"`) but nothing happens when buttons are pushed.

If I use any theme **with .Fullscreen**:
Virtual keyboards works as intented, but application crashes if scrolled with keyboard open

If I use any theme **without .Fullscreen**:
Virtual keyboard doesn't work, no more crashes.

Is there any way to prevent vertical scrolling when keyboard is up? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Navneeth Gopalakrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135909/navneeth-gopalakrishnan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656129/1969333) plus:

```
        expandList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (getWindow().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }
       });
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Yes might work if user is slow, but if you scroll edit text invisible inside listview or scrollview before soft input is not visible, the close doesn't trigger and it crashes with the trace.