# EditText doesn't show when I have focus in another

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a layout where i have one image view, two edittext and one button,
when i clicked on the first edittext, i can't scroll to the second to fill it too, because of the virtual keyboard, here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/invokeme" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="235dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:hint="@string/login" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="235dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/login"
        android:hint="@string/password" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submitLogin"
        android:layout_width="235dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="12"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more than one way around. First one may be that you can keep everything ( the whole relative layout) inside a `ScrollView`. Second way can be that you may establish a touch listener on your view, excluding the two EditText's. When anything other than those two EditText is touched, you can hide the keyboard from the screen. See [How to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext) for more. Hope it helps.