# Hide keypad in android while touching outside Edit Text Area

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, ontouchlistener, android-keypad

I know that the code for dismiss tyhe keypad in android is

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Can anyone suggest me a method to hide the keypad if we touch the area outside the text area other than the keypad in the screen.

Comment: Code seems fine. This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some cases you pass `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu)

Comment: checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext/36786783#36786783

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code to dismiss Softkeyboard is below:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

You can put it in Utility Class  or if you are defining it within an activity, avoid the activity parameter, or call hideSoftKeyboard(this).

You can write a method that iterates through every View in your activity, and check if it is an instanceof EditText if it is not register a setOnTouchListener to that component and everything will fall in place. In case you are wondering how to do that, it is in fact quite simple. Here is what you do, you write a recursive method like the following.

```
public void setupUI(View view) {

    //Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if(!(view instanceof EditText)) {

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard();
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

            setupUI(innerView);
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method after `SetcontentView()` with paramet as `id` of your view like:

```
RelativeLayoutPanel android:id="@+id/parent"> ... </RelativeLayout>
```

Then call `setupUI(findViewById(R.id.parent))`

Comment: copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext

Comment: While, the best answer in above link was this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19828165/609782 Less code, no iterations.

Answer (score 7):

Best way you can **use** is **DONE button besides EditText** make your **onClickListener** to do like,

```
done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be old but I got this working by implenting a custom class

```
public class DismissKeyboardListener implements OnClickListener { 

    Activity mAct;

    public DismissKeyboardListener(Activity act) {
        this.mAct = act;
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( v instanceof ViewGroup ) {
            hideSoftKeyboard( this.mAct );
        } 
    }        
} 

public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
        getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}
```

the best practice here is to create a Helper class and every container Relative / Linear Layouts should implement this.

**** Take note only the main Container should implement this class (For optimization) ****

and implement it like this :

```
Parent.setOnClickListener( new DismissKeyboardListener(this) );
```

the keyword this is for Activity. so if you are on fragment you use it like getActivity();

---thumbs up if it help you... --- cheers Ralph ---