# auto hides keyboard after scrolling ListView on android

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, keyboard

Im new on android please help me to auto hide after scrolling the listview here is my code but could not get right solution

xml file :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/offline_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dde1e3"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
     >
</ListView>
```

code:

```
        lvCustomList.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!hasFocus)
                hideKeyboard(v);

        }

        private void hideKeyboard(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManger = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity
                    .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManger.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11656129

Comment: @Sree what is problem with above code??

Comment: i think you are passing view, change it to activity, some times work

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this..

why don't you use `OnTouchListener` for `ListView` like below

```
lvCustomList.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this is hiding keyboard properly after touching listview but im not able to scroll the list

Comment: i got the solution on your above code 'return false' give the required solution

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `onScrollStateChanged` instead of `onScroll` and by using `scrollState == 0`. So keyboard will hide when user is really scrolling.

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                         int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == 0) {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManger = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity
                        .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManger.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: scroll state == 0 is idle? Probably want to use `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview,to hide the keyboard on scrolling - SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING ( Mentioned by @doubleA )

```java
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) recyclerView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(recyclerView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            //Hide keyboard code
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
            if (view == null) {
                view = new View(activity);
            }
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This thread is related to ListView not RecyclerView.

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManger = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity
                    .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManger.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

                }
            });
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: but this code only show keyboard for some milliseconds when im trying to search items