# How to make touchables touchable when the keyboard is shown in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an autocomplete screen where the very top is a `textInput` and below it is a list of autocompletes that are touchable. However, when the keyboard is up, I have to touch the autocompletes twice: the first time to dismiss the keyboard, and the second time to actually touch the autocomplete. How can I achieve the above with one touch.

Comment: I am not sure whether you have used scroll view or not, but you may look into this thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12784,

Answer (score 1):

Below the `textInput` where you have the list which shows all the autocompletes, usually a `ScrollView` just add this attribute to it `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'`

It should look like this :

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
    {autoCompletes}
</ScrollView>
```

The attribute `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` tells the app not to close the keyboard instead let the touch handler handle it, hence the keyboards persists its state.
Refer this post for more details :: [Ignore rest of screen when keyboard active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467304/8892206)

Answer (score 1):

`keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` or `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` is the answer for your problem.

Note: All scrollable view present within the main parent scroll view should have this attribute `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'`

Note: Flatlist is also scrollview so Flatlist also consider attribute `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'`