# close keyboard when user taps on recyclerView

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` and below there's an `EditText`. I want when user taps outside the `EditText` to close the keyboard.

I searched and find this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828165/423980) but it doesn't work for me. User taps outside but `EditText` still has focus.

My XML code is :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_chatroom_messages_list"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large" android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large" android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_chatroom_send_message"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_normal" android:hint="Type to reply"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xlarge" android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_chatroom_send_message_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pong_2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp" android:contentDescription="Send msg button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set an `onTouchListener()` to your `RecyclerView` and call the `hideKeyboard()` method from it.

Comment: not for `RecyclerView` but for main `ViewGroup` which contains both views (cutted of from posted XML), and check inside this listener if `editText.hasFocus()`

Comment: That is another way but if the `RecyclerView` covers entire screen above the EditText, then both should achieve same thing. BUT isn't EditText part of the ViewGroup? :/

Answer (score 1):

close it when your `editText` losses it's focus.

like that:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing - the problem is that it doesn't seems to look focus

Comment: when user "taps" outside `EditText` and "tapped" layout is not focusable then `EditText` still have focus...

Answer (score 1):

Call this method on recyclerview touch listener...

```
public static void hideKeyboard(final Activity activity) {
    final View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (view == null) {
                View view2 = new View(activity);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view2.getWindowToken(), 0);
            } else {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }, 125);
}
```