# The keyboard lifts up the Views in input mode

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have `Activity` with the `ScrollView`  and the `Button` in the footer. If I click on `EditText` for input text,  the keyboard lifts up the `Views`. And the `Button` and the `ScrollView` shift above of the keyboard. I need to the keyboard not to lift the `Views`, but should cover on top the `Views`.

How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/primaryLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.test.test.TestActivity">

<LinearLayout
    tools:context="com.test.myapplication.MainMenuActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGreySubHeaderBg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/content_header"/>
    <include layout="@layout/content_subheader"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
                style="@style/nls_1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                    tools:text="@string/tools_txt_nl1"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_32_bold_ellipsized" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_20px"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_20px"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
                android:background="@color/colorLightGreySubHeaderBg"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/testName"
                    android:text=""
                    tools:text="@string/tools_txt_test"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26_bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/testType"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26"
                    tools:text="@string/tools_txt_test2"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorMainWhite">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_35px"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_35px"
                        android:text="@string/txt_enter"/>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_30px"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/icontest"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_45px"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_45px"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_test"/>
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editTextTest"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconTestId"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/testAbbreviation"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_20px"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:hint="@string/txt_test"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorTxtMainBlue"
                            android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
                            style="@style/ets_lo_text_32_blue"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/testAbbreviation"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            style="@style/tvs_lo_text_32_blue"
                            tools:text="test"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorMainBlue"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_35px"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_35px"
                        android:text="@string/txt_test"/>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_30px">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iconDescriptionId"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_45px"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_45px"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_test"/>
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconDescriptionId"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_20px"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editTextTest"
                            android:hint="@string/txt_test"
                            style="@style/ets_lo_text_32_blue"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorTxtMainBlue"
                            android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:maxLines="1" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorMainBlue"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingLayoutDefaultNormal"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_blue_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your activity:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

or in your Manifest:

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, it work. Maybe you can explain how can I remove the keyboard by clicking on the free space of the ScrollView?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828165/4239410 and read the comments to know about the working in ScrollView

Comment: Thank you for link!