# Hide keyboard when user clicks else where from edit text (using fragments)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

Im trying to make it so when the user clicks away from the keyboard (any where on the page) it closes down (to be able to view page without it there as I have a key edit texts on the page they may want to fill out before..) ive tried lots of solutions and many answers on stack overflow but non seem to be working for me ...

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements BlockingStep {

public interface PassingData { //create interface to pass data
    void passData (String data);
}

String stepOne;
EditText _fromET;
EditText _toET;
EditText _refET;
EditText _numET;

private PassingData PD_listener; // declare member variable of interface

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    PD_listener = (PassingData) context; //initialize interface using onAttach method
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentone, container, false);

    _fromET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.FROM);
    _toET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.TO);
    _refET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.REF_NUM);
    _numET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.CONTACTNUM);
    return view;
}
```

I tried using inputmethodmanager and also a focusListener but both failed...

Any help would be great, thank you!
Abbie

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I stated I tried the answers of question on stack overflow similar but for my code it wasn't working...

Comment: Go with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828165/8448886

Comment: @A.Turner: Lets see what you tried.

Comment: I tried many solutions and non worked hence why I went back to original code and asked on here after I tried to fix :)

Comment: You want to hide keyboard in fragment or in activity?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan fragment please when user clicks anywhere outside the keyboard, even if its just the background

Comment: @Rohit5k2 can you please take off duplicate

Comment: else where means? out side to edittext? or inside?

Comment: outside the edit text @Adilhusen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **`OnFocusChangeListener`**

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

**you need to use this on your EditText, and whenever you click outside of the EditText anywhere it will hide the SoftKeyboard for you.**

Comment: I did try a focuschangelistener but a different way I shall try this now thank you!

Comment: yes please try this it will solve your problem

Comment: it says cant resolve locationEt, where abouts did you put this code? in oncreateview?

Comment: you need to pass there yourEditText

Comment: i updated answer to explain you clearly

Comment: in onViewCreated you need to add this

Comment: yes I have added my edit text in place of your code but I get the error 'cant resolve locationEt'

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your parent activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if ( v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                v.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Add this to your layout of the fragment:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you may try this way

```
 public static void forceHideKeyboard(AppCompatActivity activity, EditText editText) {
        try {
            if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null
                    || !(activity.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText)) {
                editText.requestFocus();
            }
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

use like this

```
forceHideKeyboard(getActivity(),editText);
```