# Handle touch outside textview after selectable text menu appears in android

Tags: android, textview

I have implemented selectable text in android via
`android:textIsSelectable="true"`

What I now need to do is make the menu disappear when there is touch anywhere other than the text/menu/cursors. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Menu after selecting text should disappear by default after clicking at any point at the screen.

Comment: It doesn't. It just stays there unless  i click the back button

Comment: @iknow Yeah, on my phone, it does not go away either (TextView, android:textIsSelectable="true").

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can follow this link to hide software keyboard/do action after click outside edittext(or any view type you want to achieve
[Handle outside click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext)

For example

```
fun setupUI(view: View, action: () -> Unit) {
// Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
if (view !is EditText && view !is AppCompatEditText) {
    view.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        action.invoke()
        false
    }
}

//If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
if (view is ViewGroup) {
    for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
        val innerView: View = view.getChildAt(i)
        setupUI(innerView, action)
    }
}
```

}

Then in your action clear your rootview focus to dismiss text copy menu: rootView.clearFocus()

Comment: Seems like that what the OP has asked about was "TextView", not "EditText", which allows text selection by default.