# TextView's selection pop-up menu is not closed when tapped elsewhere

Tags: android, textview

In the default activity created by Android Studio, I added `android:textIsSelectable="true"`. Now, if I long-press a word, it shows copy/share/select all, but when I tap elsewhere, it does not get closed. I need to either click the back button or select one item on the menu. How can I make the menu closed when I tap somewhere else?

There was the (probably) same question (although the questioner did not specify that it was a TextView, I think it was), but [the only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499651/455796) was assuming an EditText and talk about dismissing the software keyboard (which is not needed for TextView) and solving the problem by adding a listener to all views other than EditText. Seems kind of a dirty way. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a structure like this: `CoordinatorLayout` > `ConstraintLayout` > `TextView`. I already had the following attributes on the `CoordinatorLayout`, to aid in dismissing the keyboard when tapping "outside" any `EditText`s:

```xml
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

But I just found out you can add `android:contextClickable="true"` to automatically "dismiss" any text selections. **Note** though that the `focus*` attributes **are still necessary**. The `contextClickable` attribute also seems to exist for at least `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and `ConstraintLayout`, so I'm pretty sure it's a standard layout feature and you don't require anything special. Now, except for some "unusual" views like `ScrollView` I can tap pretty much anywhere in the activity to dismiss the text selection. Or more specifically: anywhere within the `CoordinatorLayout`, but since it's set to `match_parent` it simply fills out the entire activity.

I'm not sure if there are any side effects of enabling `contextClickable`, but so far I haven't noticed any odd behaviour. Apparently a "context click" means something similar to right-click on computers. I'm guessing (standard) layouts have a default listener for it, which causes any existing context menus (like the text selection popup) to close and it simply won't open any of its own.